# Webcam stopped working after updating Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, thinkpad, camera, v4l2loopback

I updated 2 days ago and my webcam stopped working.

- The following softwares do not detect my built-in webcam:

  - Zoom
  - Discord
  - Chromium
- `/dev/video` is not present.
- `/dev/video0` is not present.
- The camera works fine in MS Windows.

I've tried:

- Rebooting
- Reinstalling `v4l2loopback-dkms` and rebooting
- `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`

  - This creates /dev/video0 corresponding to a dummy video device.
- `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

Details:

- Laptop: ThinkPad P14s
- Kernel: 5.13.4-arch2-1

Does anyone have a clue how I can go about fixing my laptop's built-in webcam?

Comment: Do you have the option to boot the older kernel?

Answer (score 1):

A [comment on Reddit r/archlinux](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/orm1ru/comment/h6ji0tp/) suggested to install a **firmware-update for the USB host controller** like `upd72020x-fw` (Renesas uPD720201 / uPD720202 USB 3.0 chipsets firmware):

> For the Webcam issue on ThinkPad P14s, some said (read it on r/thinkpad but can't remember which post) to use this driver from AUR:
>
> https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/upd72020x-fw/
>
> Screen tearing, suspend/hibernate issues are usually related to graphic card driver. Blacklisting the discrete graphic card might just solve the issue.

After the firmware-update my issue was fixed.

For other users experiencing a similar problem, I suggest looking to see if there are alternative drivers that are more suited for your setup.